# Woocommerce Wordpress Custom Pricing Field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );
function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    $custom_price = 10; // This will be custom price
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
    }
}
```

The above code gives the custom price 10 for all products in the cart and check out but I have been trying to get the custom price through the custom field I have created which is named as 'rrp_price' for different products. I have stuck to get the custom price into the cart and check out. So can anyone help me? I also tried:

```
$custom_price = "<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'rrp_price', true ); ?>";
```

But it didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify all the prices for items with a `rrp_price` field set by filtering the price.

```
function so_25524453_get_price( $price, $product ){
    if( $rrp = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'rrp_price', true ) ){
        $price = $rrp;
    }
    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'so_25524453_get_price', 10, 2 );
```